# Pacemaker configuration for xCAT

Tags: pacemaker, corosync

I'm looking to set up an xCAT HA solution using this guide: https://xcat-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/hamn/setup_ha_mgmt_node_with_drbd_pacemaker_corosync.html

Unfortunately this guide is fairly old and outdated. I've got most of it working but I'm having issues with the pcs commands that should sort out the ordering such as:

```
pcs -f xcat_cfg constraint order list ip_xCAT db_xCAT
```

There are several of these lines in the config but this command does not seem to be valid. Is anyone able to assist with what this/these line(s) should be?

TIA
Pete

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to use "order set" rather than "order list"